# How do I tell why it takes so long to boot up/login?

Tags: boot, log

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 on a pretty new laptop, but it takes longer than I think it should (since the laptop is quite new) to start up and log in for the first time after booting. If I log out and log in again, it works in seconds, but starting up (before the splash screen displays) and logging in for the first time (after it displays the desktop but before the UI and the desktop items appear) take over 15 seconds each. It may or may not be important that I still use lightdm, but have swapped out Gnome 3 instead of Unity. Below are links to my /var/log/dmesg and /var/log/boot.log.
Thanks for your help!
Thomas

[/var/log/dmesg](http://pastebin.com/YirncpEy)

[/var/log/boot.log](http://pastebin.com/zNa6g7nF)

Comment: @TomBrossman I do not second the duplicate... The problem with bootchart is that it normally stops too early to see what happens between the graphic login and an usable interface (I have the same problem in a pure gdm - gnome shell system). Probably a(nother) gnome-shell bug...

Comment: Looking at the dmesg, there is a 16 seconds pause just before "adding swap" line. I have exactly the same symptom. Time to search around...